# Try to get instagram API

Tags: c#, api, instagram

I need some help, i try to get instagram api in my application( windows forms) but not success.My code is like this:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["client_id"] = "client_id"; 
    data["client_secret"] = "client_secret";
    data["username"] = "user"
    data["password"] = "pass"
    data["grant_type"] = "password";
    var response = wb.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "POST", data);
    string json = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
```

But after run this give me the error:

```
{
"code": 400,
"error_type": "OAuthException",
"error_message": "This client is not xAuth enabled"
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you read any documentation on the instagram API?

Answer (score 1):

From the description of the error the values you are passing in for `data["client_id"]` and `data["client_secret"]` are not authorized to use the API. Make sure you have [registered your application](https://instagram.com/developer/) and you are using the correct two values that where given to you during your registration.

Also check that your app is authorized to use `data["grant_type"] = "password";`. From reading their API password based authentication is not allowed, you must use "redirect based" authentications to be able to authenticate with their API.

**EDIT:** Found this in the documentation under Step 3 for [server side authentication](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

> **grant_type:** authorization_code is currently the only supported value

So your grant type of `password` and passing the username and password is definitely the problem.

Comment: I checked client_id and client_secret and seems fine.

Comment: Then the problem is from the 2nd pargaraph I talked about, They do not let you pass the username and password directly. You must direct them to a web page instagram controls then use the token that web page returns in your authentication. See [Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)